# Change csv file delimiter in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a number of .csv files with tab delimiter and now I want to change the delimiter. 
When I use the below script it does not change the file. Please help me with the script.

```
file_mask=$1
from_delim=$2
to_delim=$3
for i in `ls $file_mask*`
do
sed -i 's|$from_delim|$to_delim|g' $i
done
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Note that `$from_delim` and `$to_delim` in `sed` won't be evaluated unless you use double quotes `"`

Comment: i used double quotes as well and i did't get any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for the sed body so the shell variables can be expanded:

```
sed -i "s|$from_delim|$to_delim|g" $i
```

Better hope neither $from_delim nor $to_delim contain a pipe.

Also, [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- don't need the for loop at all:

```
sed -i "s|$from_delim|$to_delim|g" ${file_mask}*
```

---

verify differences:

```
file_mask=$1
from_delim=$2
to_delim=$3

sed -i.bak "s|$from_delim|$to_delim|g" $file_mask*

for f in $file_mask*; do
    diff -q $f $f.bak >/dev/null
    if (( $? != 1 )); then
        echo "no changes made to $f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @glenn jackman. it's working.  but i have doubt when i use this sed -i 's|\t|^|g' it is changing the files. why not in loop?

Comment: You don't need the loop because if you give multiple files to `sed -i` it will edit each one in turn: sed loops over the files by itself.

Comment: Okay. after changing the files, i want to do a scan as well whether the file is changed or not. so that i am very sure about the number of files changed as well. can you help me how should i use if condition.

Comment: If the delimiter is quoted within a field a mere `sed` or `tr` will be not sufficient. You should have balanced quotes you might still be able to use `sed` but it becomes cumbersome: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/remove-comma-between-the-quotes-only-in-a-comma-delimited-file. Better to use csvtool e.g.

Answer (score 14):

Do not use `sed` or `tr` for this, use `csvtool` (available from common repositories). If you have TABs in strings the above simple tools will choke. You will need to use `awk` to start counting quotes, etc. It's gonna be a mess with these basic tools.

To replace TABs with e.g. semi-colons with csvtool including all corner cases is simple:

`csvtool -t TAB -u ';' cat $ifile -o $ofile`

With `$ifile` the input file and `$ofile` the output file.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `tr`:

```
tr '\t' ',' < inputfile > outfile
```

(assuming that `,` is the new delimiter)

Comment: This can potentially damage the file if there is a TAB in a field

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using csvkit: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. With csvformat that comes with the package, you can safely change delimiter.

```
csvformat -D '[your delimiter here]' [file name]
```